# What is the xpath to extract the Total pages. I want to extract 111?

Tags: python, xpath

I want to extract total pages from the code below. Please hep me to wirte it. I want my answer to be 111.

`<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_litRecords" class="hidden-xs">Showing 1 - 500 of 55385 records. [Total pages: 111]</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Python with Selenium bindings**. You can use `.split` on `:` to get the `first element` and then apply `replace ]` with empty space.

**Code :**

```
html = '''
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_litRecords" class="hidden-xs">Showing 1 - 500 of 55385 records. [Total pages: 111]</span>
'''
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

str = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_litRecords' and @class='hidden-xs']").text
desired_text = str.split(':')[1].replace(']', '').strip()
print(desired_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure XPath: `substring-before(substring-after(//span[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_litRecords'], '[Total pages: '), ']')`.